# Creating vertical timelines with Javascript/jQquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, timeline

I saw other questions about libraries to create timelines with Javascript. There are some libraries, but they create horizontal timelines, but I want to create a vertical.

So, which is a good library to create vertical timelines?

I don't want a timeline like Facebook with posts, but  a simple timeline with years and items like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700419/alternative-to-simile-timeline-for-timeline-visualization), but vertical instead of horizontal.

Comment: apply css rotation by 90 degree to horizontal timelines. Problem solved.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have a jQuery plugin to create a simple vertical timeline. See [this](http://www.technotarek.com/timeliner/) for background and [this](http://technotarek.com/timeliner/demo-future/timeliner-future.html) for a demo.

Comment: Just released version 2.0. See https://github.com/technotarek/timeliner or the updated demo (linked above).

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do a FB like timeline jQuery mansonry is quite good and with a bit of CSS is enough to create the core timeline. Then add what you want to it, I know there is even a tutorial out there for it but can't find it. http://masonry.desandro.com/

Otherwise there is [this](https://github.com/chimericdream/jquery-vertical-timeline) project

Here is the FB timeline [tutorial](http://www.9lessons.info/2012/01/facebook-timeline-design-using-jquery.html), not the best but help getting the basic in place

Comment: Masonry is pretty nice.. but I really don't know how its related to a timeline. Masonry to me is more for creating things like pintrest.

Comment: It's just what I used to create one, can't show code cos work stuff, but I just followed a tutorial. As you need divs on each side of the bar they will have massive spaces, which is were masonry comes in.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for https://github.com/balancemedia/Timeline

This uses [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) to create series of events, in a vertically time-sorted structure.