# Need to make a vertical timeline

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeline

I need to make a vertical javascript timeline like below link which is now created with flash.
Can someone give me a reference plugin? Or kindly advice me is it possible with plane javascript or javascript frameworks. I have little bit idea about plane javascript and jquery.

http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/interactive/2011/mar/22/middle-east-protest-interactive-timeline

I did some research on it. But did't get any good result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry for forgot to mention one thing. I need to scale the items on scrolling or moving

Comment: Hiya, this should help you out, exactly same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418534/creating-vertical-timelines-with-javascript-jqquery

Comment: @ Tats_innit Thanks for quick reply. I have already saw this question and samples. I am trying to make the plugin almost same as above URL in my question. With sacle, path, easing effect etc.

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/balancemedia/Timeline
Demo: http://builtbybalance.com/github-timeline/

there could be some more: https://github.com/search?langOverride=&language=JavaScript&q=timeline&repo=&start_value=1&type=Repositories

A good tutorial: 
http://www.9lessons.info/2012/01/facebook-timeline-design-using-jquery.html

Answer (score 0):

the whole thing is done in flash. you can achieve this in javascript(definitely with css), but there is not straight forward method for it. Even in flash it wasn't done in a straight forward method. It took some efforts to sync the movements of the timeline and the events path. start with developing custom scroll bar using javascript and css, and then develop the rest.

Comment: @ Tirtha Thanks for your replay, I am also trying to start with jScrollPane. But I have no idea how to give scale effect for inside items.

Comment: @user1374554 i think you need to use css3 perspective feature. it'll five the perfect scale effect you are looking for.