# Create timeline chart in HTML/JS/CSS

Tags: javascript, html

I need some help or concept from all of you. I want to create a timeline chart with web technology to display tasks that have start and end date on web browser. What technology or concept to create a timeline graphic chart on the browser would be helpful?

Comment: With HTML5, for better effects you may use [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/).

Comment: you can have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418534/creating-vertical-timelines-with-javascript-jqquery and http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2011/09/28/7-beautiful-web-based-timeline-using-javascript-and-css/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Using preexisting tools:**

You could build a calendar using a number of calendar plugins that exist, like [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) for jQuery, or any of [these other plugins](http://www.queness.com/post/656/10-beautiful-jquery-and-mootool-calendar-plugins).

Timeline sliders exist, also for jQuery, like [Timeline JS](http://timeline.verite.co/), [jQuery Timelinr](http://www.csslab.cl/2011/08/18/jquery-timelinr/), [Timeglider](http://timeglider.com/jquery/) or [Tiki-Toki](http://www.tiki-toki.com/), of which I think the last sounds more aptly suited to your cause.

Comment: Timeline JS is beautiful and has a native feel!

Comment: I think it make sense to add https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline

Answer (score 0):

you could try http://functionn.blogspot.com/2012/03/timeline-javascript-library-for.html

or any of the following:

http://functionn.blogspot.com/search/label/timelines

:)

Comment: Dead links... Please, fix them!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a super-simple, non-interactive, way of displaying timeline data in a few lines of HTML, you can use the Google Charts API to do it. Here's a self-contained example: https://gist.github.com/KorkyPlunger/16c540f7b622b8906c1351e44bf1bf3c