# Implementing a Javascript library/projects for multiple vertical timelines with zoom controls

Tags: javascript, html, visualization, data-visualization, timeline

> Note: Please let me know if this question is not relevant to SO. I
>   will happily remove it

I am looking for a javascript-based library or a sample project which supports creating multiple (child) and vertical timelines. There are many horizontal ones with these features but I couldn't find a proper vertical timeline. More details are as follows:

**What I am specifically looking for:**

1. Zoom in/out controls on a selected period of time.
2. To be able to create child/multiple timelines on main timeline
3. A vertical timeline

**A graphical representation of my question:**

[image: screenshot]

**Explanation:**

- A - Zoom control (as a minimap)
- B - Vertical timeline
- C - Main timeline alone with child ones
- D - Text/details related to points on the
  timeline

**What I have found so far:**

- [Timeliner](https://technotarek.com/timeliner/demo-future/timeliner-future.html) - no support for child timelines
- [GitGraph](http://gitgraphjs.com/) - not really a timeline, but it has child timelines (sort of), no zooming as well
- [Tik Tok](http://datanews.github.io/tik-tok/examples/) - no support for child timelines

I have gone through many StackOverflow questions and answers but couldn't find anything close to what I am looking for. The closest question I found :

[Creating vertical timelines with Javascript/jQquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418534/creating-vertical-timelines-with-javascript-jqquery)

I just wanted to know whether I am trying to reinvent the wheel if there's anything similar out there. My plan is to combine the above-mentioned libraries, if everything else fails.

Please also let me know if this question is not relevant and should be shifted to a different StackExchange space.

Thank you

Comment: do you have any solution for this problem?

Comment: Sorry @ArtemBernatskyi unfortunately, I still don't have a solution for this